# CART analysis with multiple dependent variables

Tags: cart

I want to do a CART analysis with **multiple dependent variables.** Which program is able to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the loss function of the tree to operate over all $m$ responses at once, then you want a multivariate tree. I am aware of two pieces of software that can do this, both are packages for R; **mvpart** and **party**. **mvpart** is an extension to the familiar **rpart** package whilst **party** implements something different using conditional inference trees.

See the paper by Glenn De'ath cited in the **mvpart** documentation for details of how the package extends the recursive partitioning idea to multivariate trees and for details on the loss function used; it is based on dissimilarities and is within node sums of squares using the default settings, IIRC.

Comment: Very helpful! Thx